# Using Google+ API for login in Android app

Tags: android, google-api, google-plus

I'm trying to use Google+ API for login in my Android app. I already enabled the API for my account but now I'm facing problem with initializing the PlusClient.

I'm following this directions https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#step_3_initialize_the_plusclient and I need to import this into my project:

```
import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;
```

Sadly Eclipse is showing this error for each input:

> The import com.google.android.gms cannot be resolved

My build target is set to Google APIs 17, google-play-service_lib is added as library, there is also android-support-v4.jar and I have no clue what is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Check that your project is correctly using google-play-services_lib as a library.

In Eclipse, go to **Project > Properties > Android** and check that **google-play-services_lib** is listed under the Library section - and that it has a green tick next to it, not a red cross.

If **google-play-services_lib** has a red cross next to it, select it and click **Remove**.  Then re-add it.

To add google-play-services_lib if it is missing, click **Add...** and Eclipse will list the available library projects in your workspace.  Select **google-play-services_lib** and click OK.